# How can I change App.xaml build action from Application Definition to Page

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core

I want make mutex, so I tried change App.xaml build action from AppDefinition To Page, then vs2019 said below:

```
An error has occurred while saving the edited properties listed below:
    Build Action
One or more values are invalid. Cannot add 'App.xaml' to the project, because the path is explicitly excluded from the project (C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100-preview8-013656\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop.targets (57,5)).
```

I tried commented out, but then my app doesn't work.

How can I change build action?

Comment: Can you create a Program.cs with a Main function, and within that create the mutex? Then if the mutex isn't createdNew, use a Thread with the ApartmentState set to STA and the menthod App.Main to start the WPF application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you target .NET Core you should implement your custom `Main` method as usual and then edit the `.csproj` file to include a `<StartupObject>` element that specifies the type where your custom `Main` method is defined instead of changing the build action of `App.xaml`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <Version>1.0.5</Version>
    <StartupObject>WpfCoreApp1.MyProgramClass</StartupObject>
</PropertyGroup>
```